# Scala Play Test Server serving static content

Tags: scala, playframework, integration-testing, scalatest

I have a question. I am using trying to test using webbrowser, therefore I went to the playframework documentation site. However, I don't want my whole application to run, which is obviously going on here:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithScalaTest

But what I want to achieve is not this. I have multiple html files, which I want to serve on a server without my application. Just a typical test server, where I will make my request to test application.

So for example: I have 2 html files called test1.html and test2.html in directory called testing and I would like to able to make requests to sites such as localhost:8080/testing/test1.html and localhost:8080/testing/test2.html to get resources which I provided before. Is it possible using play?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a fully fledged web framework to serve static files. You can use plain NGINX to serve your static files from a remote server.

Take a look at this:
[Serving Static Content with Nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/)
And here is a nice Tutorial: [A guide to hosting static websites using NGINX](https://medium.com/@jgefroh/a-guide-to-using-nginx-for-static-websites-d96a9d034940)

Comment: However, I want to be able to test my whole application. And then close the server. So for example, I would like to be able to run all my tests, which would start the server, then make requests to that server and close all of it. And the only thing that i have done would be typing one command.

Comment: haa now I got it. Do you have this static server already providing the static html files somehow? with nginx or apache for example?

Comment: Right now, I am using xampp which uses apache. I have all the files in the folder, which is served on this server. However, I want to move my whole server to scala without need of starting whole apache server.